# constraint programing scheduling

Tags: cplex, cp, opl

I have no idea how to write these constraints in cplex.

A care facility requires exactly one security guard on duty every hour of every day. A
24-hour calendar day is broken up into three 8 hour shifts: D(ay), E(vening) and N(ight).
Find a two week schedule for the care facility that uses 6 guards and that ensures the
following employment requirements are met:

1. If a guard works on a calendar day, then they work on the previous and/or next
   day
2. The schedule of every guard is forward rotating. That is, given any pair of
   consecutive calendar days that a guard works, the allowable assignments are: D
   D, D E, D N, E E, E N, or N N.

3)The schedule is cyclical: the 15th day of the schedule is the first day of the
schedule, etc…, and all rules apply across the 14th to first day boundary.

Answer (score 0):

as a starting point you could use the [Decision Management Community challenge April 2020](https://dmcommunity.files.wordpress.com/2020/04/challenge2020april.opl_.alexfleischer-1.pdf)

The challenge was [doctor planning](https://dmcommunity.org/challenge/challenge-apr-2020/)

```
range days=1..7;
range weekend=5..7;
int Friday=5;
int Saturday=6;
int Sunday=7;

{string} doctors={"Fleming","Freud","Heimlich","Eustachi","Golgi"};
{string} shifts={"early","late","night"};

assert card(doctors)==5;

tuple t
{
  string doctor;
  int day;
  string shift;
}

{t} availabilities with doctor in doctors =
{<"Fleming",d,s> | d in {Friday,Saturday,Sunday},s in shifts}
union
{<"Freud",d,s> | d in days, s in {"early","late"}}
union 
{<"Heimlich",d,s> | d in days,s in shifts : !((d in weekend) && (s=="night"))}
union
{<"Eustachi",d,s> | d in days,s in shifts}
union
{<"Golgi",d,s> | d in days,s in shifts}
;

// is that doctor working that day that shift ?
dvar boolean x[doctors][days][shifts]; 


// number of shifts per doctor
dvar int nbShifts[doctors];


// minimize max-min of nbShifts
minimize 
max(d in doctors) nbShifts[d]-min(d in doctors) nbShifts[d];

// constraints
subject to
{
  // nb of shifts
  forall(d in doctors) 
  nbShifts[d]==sum(i in days,s in shifts) x[d][i][s];
  
  // a doctor can only work one shift a day
  
  forall(d in doctors,i in days) sum(s in shifts) x[d][i][s]<=1;
  
  // specific constraints per doctor
  
  forall(d in doctors,i in days,s in shifts:<d,i,s> not in availabilities)
    x[d][i][s]==0;
    
   // max 2 night shifts for Golgi
   
   sum(d in days) x["Golgi"][d]["night"]<=2;
  
  // night shift ==> next day off or next night shift
  
  forall(d in doctors,i in days:(i+1) in days)
   { 
     (x[d][i]["night"]==1) => (x[d][i+1]["early"]==0);
     (x[d][i]["night"]==1) => (x[d][i+1]["late"]==0);
  }   
  
  // periodic timetable add on
  
  forall(d in doctors)
   { 
     (x[d][Sunday]["night"]==1) => (x[d][1]["early"]==0);
     (x[d][Sunday]["night"]==1) => (x[d][1]["late"]==0);
  }   
  
  // both days of the week end or none
  
  forall(d in doctors) 
     sum(s in shifts) x[d][Saturday][s]==sum(s in shifts) x[d][Sunday][s];
  
  //  1 and only 1 doctor per shift
  
  forall(i in days,s in shifts) sum(d in doctors)  x[d][i][s]==1;
  
}


string whichDoctor[d in days][s in shifts]=
   first({doc | doc in doctors:x[doc][d][s]==1});

execute display
{
for(var d in days)
{
  write("Day ",d," : ");
  for(var s in shifts) write(whichDoctor[d][s]," ");
  writeln();
}
}
```